# how to indent an html list of lists using xslt?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, text-processing

How do I equally indent each resulting "record" node in the resulting html?

xml:

```
<csv>
  <record>
    <entry>Reported_Date</entry>
    <entry>HA</entry>
    <entry>Sex</entry>
    <entry>Age_Group</entry>
    <entry>Classification_Reported</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-01-26</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-02</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>50-59</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>20-29</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-11</entry>
    <entry>Interior</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-20</entry>
    <entry>Fraser</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-21</entry>
    <entry>Fraser</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-27</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>60-69</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
</csv>
```

xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="csv">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Reported Date</th>
                <th>HA</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Age_Group</th>
                <th>Classification_Reported</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>

            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>Reported_Date</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>HA</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Sex</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Age_Group</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Classification_Reported</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>Reported_Date</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>HA</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Sex</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Age_Group</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Classification_Reported</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-01-26</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>M</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>40-49</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-01-26</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>M</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>40-49</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-02</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>F</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>50-59</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-02</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>F</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>50-59</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-05</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>F</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>20-29</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-05</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>F</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>20-29</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-05</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>M</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>30-39</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-05</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>M</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>30-39</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-11</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Interior</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>F</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>30-39</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-11</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Interior</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>F</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>30-39</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-20</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Fraser</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>F</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>30-39</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-20</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Fraser</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>F</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>30-39</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-21</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Fraser</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>M</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>40-49</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-21</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Fraser</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>M</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>40-49</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


            <li>

               <ul>
                  <li>2020-02-27</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>F</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>60-69</li>
               </ul>

               <ul>
                  <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
               </ul>

            </li>

            <ul>
               <li>2020-02-27</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Vancouver Coastal</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>F</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>60-69</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
               <li>Lab-diagnosed</li>
            </ul>


         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

the html should be more along the lines of a list of "record" nodes, within each record a list of "entry" nodes with text.  So that the details, such as date, etc, are indented for each record with each of the records equally indented.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context.

Comment: I shortened the `xml` to that end, @michael.hor257k

Comment: I don't see any indenting issue after applying your XSLT to your XML: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZYrpB I also don't see any connection between the output received and the output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Indenting varies from one XSLT processor to another and you haven't told us which one you are using, however, with this kind of XML input you'll probably get better results if you add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to the stylesheet: this gets rid of the ignorable whitespace in the source document, which is probably finding its way through to the result document.